# Literature reference on average ranking

Tags: mean, references, ranking

Does anyone have a literature reference on application of average (weighted) ranking in scientific publications (biology, chemistry)?

An example is this paper, with application in algorithm ranking:
http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/specific/congreso/brazdil00comparison.pdf

Here the algorithms are ranked by three different measured error rates from 1 to last. Then, an average rank is calculated from these three, which gives some kind of "total rank".

Comment: You are going to need to say more here. It isn't even clear if this is a question about statistics.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have edited my question, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: A similar Q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472277/calculate-average-for-5-star-review-system-based-on-average-and-quantity-of-revi